# Finding probability of a standard deck of 52 French (Bridge) cards

Tags: probability

[image]

Need some help here, I am confused here. I got 2.   Probability = (1/36)*(1/4^4) = 0.000109, but my prof told me that I am wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mind explaining how you got this answer? Seems a bit weird.

Comment: Possibly worth remarking:  if you look up any of the (easily found) references on poker probability,  "straights" almost always exclude "straight flushs" and "Royal flushes".  Your phrasing suggests that you do not intend that exclusion, but of course in that case you'll end up with a different answer than the standard sites give.  And those sites almost certainly allow both high and low aces.

Comment: Another point of clarification:  I've never seen any one claim that, say, $QKA23$ was a straight, if that's what you mean by "cyclic".  I have seen contexts in which you allow either $A2345$ or $10JQKA$ but not both, though almost always you allow both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it upside down.  There are $36\cdot4^4$ straights.  You have to divide this by the number of ways to draw $5$ cards.  That is $$\frac{36\cdot4^4}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

Comment: Are you sure that the denominator would be only (52/5)? Wouldn't it come as a binomial coefficient ?

Comment: I got the answer, it will be combination of 52 cards with 5 cards drawn amongst those. Therefore, it will be 52C5. Therefore, the output will be 36*4^4/(52C5). Thanks!!

Comment: $\binom{52}{5}$ means $_{52}C_5$

Comment: Oh I am sorry I thought thats 52/5 what you meant. My bad.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun No problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is what I did to get the answer, but I think I did some mistake somewhere.

Comment: If you are not certain your answer is correct, you should include your attempt in your question rather than posting it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry I didnt know that.